# Help with Apex trigger that updates all child Contact records when Account is updated

Tags: apex, trigger

I am creating my very first Apex trigger and am having trouble with the syntax.

I have a formula field in the Contact object that pulls in the Industry field from the Account. When an account is updated and the Industry is changed, I want the child Contacts to  update (no changes to data) so that my "on update" workflow runs (which triggers an outbound message to update my external ERP through Jitterbit).

**I have an error:** 
Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [LIST].keySet() at line 6 column 20

**I would also like the trigger to fire only when the industry is changed.**

My code is below:

```
trigger UpdateContactsWithNewCustomerType on Account (after update) {

  If(Trigger.isUpdate){

  Set<ID> ids = Trigger.new.keySet();
  List<Account> updatedParents = [SELECT Id, 
     (select ID, AccountID from Contacts) 
      FROM Account 
      WHERE Id in :ids];
  List<Contact> childrenToUpdate = new List<Contact>();
  for (Account p : updatedParents) 
    { 

    for(Contact kid : p.Contacts) 
     {                      
       childrenToUpdate.add(kid);
      }
        }
  if( !childrenToUpdate.isEmpty )
     {
     update childrenToUpdate;
    }
  }  
}
```

*** UPDATE ***
Thanks to both @Ralph and @Regal I was able to get this working. Below is the final code that worked.

```
trigger UpdateContactsWithNewCustomerType on Account (after update) {
//CREATE NEW LIST ids THAT CONTAINS ACCOUNT IDS SENT TO TRIGGER
 Set<ID> ids = Trigger.newMap.keySet();

// FIND ALL ACCOUNTS WHERE ID = THOSE SENT TO TRIGGER
List<Account> updatedParents = [SELECT Id, Industry, (select ID, AccountID from Contacts) 
    FROM Account 
    WHERE Id in :ids];

//CREATE NEW EMPTY LIST CALLED childrenToUpdate
List<Contact> childrenToUpdate = new List<Contact>();

//LOOP OVER UPDATED ACCOUNTS
for(Account acc : updatedParents)
 { // CHECK IF THE NEW AND OLD INDUSTRY VALUES ARE THE SAME
  String oldvalue = Trigger.oldMap.get(acc.Id).Industry;
  String newValue = acc.Industry;

 //IF NOT, THEN ADD IDS OF RELATED CONTACTS TO childrenToUpdate LIST
 if(oldvalue != newValue )
  {
    for(Contact kid: acc.Contacts) 
     {                      
       childrenToUpdate.add(kid);
     }

  }
}

//UPDATE CONTACTS IF childrenToUpdate IS NOT EMPTY
if( !childrenToUpdate.isEmpty() )
{ 
  update childrenToUpdate;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Trigger.newMap` instead of `List` as explained by [Ralph](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/594/ralph) in the answer.

In addition, to check the condition if the industry is changed or not there is an another Trigger context variable `Trigger.oldMap` where you can get previous value of field and this provide ability to compare the changes in record after update.

Ex:

```
for(Account acc : Trigger.newMap)
{
     Id oldvalue = Trigger.oldMap.get(acc.Id).Industry_Field__c;
     Id newValue = acc.Industry_Field__c;

     // check if industry field changed or not
     if(oldvalue != newValue )
     {
        // Proceed
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Trigger.new` is a list and you're calling the `keySet()` method on it, but that method only works for maps. You can use `Trigger.newMap` instead which does have a `keySet()` method.